# SetLocale with value "en_FR"

Tags: jsp, jstl

Hi I am new to JSP so sorry if my question is trivial. I tried to to research the answer with no luck.

Can anyone explain why the following wouldn't work

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_FR" />  
<fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}
```

the current date/time will be shown in en_US locale.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en_FR` means: *in English, with the particularities of the English language from France*. Since English isn't an official language in France, the JVM doesn't have any specific settings for the English locale in France, so it falls back to `en`: English.

And since there isn't anything different regarding dates between `en` and `en_US`, the format is the same.

Here's some test, and what it displays:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_FR" />
In English (FR): <fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" />
In English (US): <fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="en_UK" />
In English (UK): <fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="en" />
In English: <fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="fr" />
In French: <fmt:formatDate value="${dt}" type="both" var="now" />${now}<br/>
```

Display:

```
In English (FR): Jan 23, 2012 2:40:24 PM
In English (US): Jan 23, 2012 2:40:24 PM
In English (UK): Jan 23, 2012 2:40:24 PM
In English: Jan 23, 2012 2:40:24 PM
In French: 23 janv. 2012 14:40:24
```

Comment: Hi Nizet,thanks for your answer. Just to correct 1 thing when Local in "en" it also default to US pattern. to get the UK one the locale needs to be "en_GB".

Comment: Of course it follows the language. A language code is used to choose the language. Then, a country code is used to have the sepecificities of this country. A language is spoken in many countries, and a country uses many languages. I wrote a blog post about that some time ago: http://jnizet.free.fr/?p=88

Comment: Your locale code definition is wrong: I've made some test in java the conclusion is clear: "en_FR" is legal and means english language , located in france. for instance the GMT date 07/02/2014 18:28:00 for one particular date formating shows "Fri, 07 Feb 2014 18:28:00 GMT" if locale is "en_UK" , shows "ven., 07 févr. 2014 19:28:00 CET" if locale is "fr_FR" and shows "Fri, 07 feb 2014 19:28:00 CET" if locale is "en_FR"

Comment: Err, where did I tell that this locale was illegal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare Dates in France in US..I would do as below..

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"  />

<fmt:setLocale value="fr_FR" scope="session"/>
Date in France:
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full"/> <br/>

<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
Date in US: 
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full" /> <br/>
```

The output is as..

```
Date in France: mercredi 14 janvier 2015  
Date in US: Wednesday, January 14, 2015
```