# Java Locale and date format

Tags: java, locale

I just don't get it. There is a site that supports only English and German languages. And there is an option for a user to specify his country so that dates, numbers and other locale-specific data would appear in an appropriate format.

The Locale is build as `Locale locale = new Locale(lang, country)`. The date is being formatted as follows:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
System.out.println("Date " + df.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Today is `26 Nov 2013`, and here is what people see depending on their country and chosen language:

1. `11/26/13` sees a person from US looking at English page, locale `en_US`, ok.
2. `26/11/13` sees a person from UK looking at English page, locale `en_GB`, ok.
3. `11/26/13` sees a person from France looking at English page, locale `en_FR`, **wrong**.

The latter should see `26/11/13` (French people here agree with me) as the date format is country-specific, isn't it? What am I missing here?

**Update**
The question is simple: why Locale("en", "FR") produces wrong date format?

**Update 2**
I'd appreciate if someone could explain (as a pat of an answer) why Java does not take into consideration the country when it comes to date format, which (in my POV) is purely country specific.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I've read it multiple times now, and I'm still not 100% sure what you are doing. Have you read the documentation of the methods that you are using? en_FR may indicate that the user is an American person living in France.

Comment: @Izmaki, sure I've read all of it. Language is English, Country is France, what date format would you expect in this case? The one I'm getting is wrong.

Comment: @Osw - based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971593/setlocale-with-value-en-fr), sounds `en_FR` will fail back to `en_US`.

Comment: "Wrong" is up to the guys writing the spec.  In this case Apple says it's right.

Comment: @HotLicks - it's actually Java; this has nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: @admdrew, well, Locale has multiple internal formats, dates, numbers, etc. And the date format is 100% country-specific and language-independent, why would it "fall back"?

Comment: Read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972570/1454048) from my original link.

Comment: @admdrew - Then make it Oracle.  Same difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English is not official language in France, so there's no specific settings in any JVM for the English language in France. In result your locale changes back to English (`en` which default implementation is `en_US`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971593/setlocale-with-value-en-fr) you can find full explanation.

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) you can find all locales supported in JDK 7 and JRE 7 and there's no `en_FR` one.

> **Update 2** I'd appreciate if someone could explain (as a pat of an answer) why Java does not take into consideration the country when it comes to date format, which (in my POV) is purely country specific.

Date format may be country-specific, but you're creating `Locale` object which is predefined (not created dynamically). If JVM did not implement locale `en_FR` then it cannot return `Locale` which is mix of partialy-English-partialy-French. It just returns some specified object - the closest one is `en`. It's just how it's implemented. If it returned `fr` one then user could feel little uncomfortable since he wanted to display page in some kind of `English` dialect.

Comment: Still don't get why purely **country-specific** part of the locale would need to fall back to English.

Comment: @Osw JVM tries to use English dialect used in France. If there's no such dialect (`Locale`) - it uses `en` Locale which is (by default) extended to `en_US`

Answer (score 2):

The `LocaleServiceProviderPool` that is used to look up locale-specific objects ultimately uses `java.util.Locale#equals` to determine if it has a match.  It does not differentiate between functions that "only care about language" or "only care about country."  There's nothing pre-defined for English in France, so it reverts to default.

Comment: I definitely see one predefined thing for English in France - short date format. Of course if language means language in Java, and country means country))

Comment: Hmm, what version of JDK are you looking in?  Is it the same as your deployment environment?  There is definitely nothing in 1.6.0_26 which is what I happen to have installed at the moment.

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18) if it matters

Comment: Oops, sorry, `java.util.Locale#equals` slipped my attention, along with 'pre-defined' word it now makes sense to me, finally. You were first to answer, but I accept Maciej's answer if you don't mind))